# Problema com python + json + urllib error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: json

Não consigo utilizar o json e urllib obtenho um erro, estou achando que o erro é por causa do sistema, eu utilizo windows! já pesquisei muito e não vejo solução para essse erro. O código é bem simple :

```
    import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request


with urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
   html = response.read().decode('utf-8')

print(html)

data = json.loads(html)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

ocorre o erro:

```
    File "D:\Marcus\Projetos\Programação\Python\Study\Json\HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources\urllib_json.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = json.loads(html)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Uso:
Python 3.6.5, Windows 10

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: acho que é porque você não está passando um json

Comment: Olá, Anderson. Sou iniciante na linguagem, comecei a prender a alguns meses. e não entendi o que vc escreveu como assim "não está passando um json" ?

Comment: Anderson. obrigado dúvida de iniciante mesmo, acho que agora entendi. Valeu mesmo cara!

Comment: Você está pegando um html e passando para uma função que recebe um json, sendo assim a função não funciona pois não foi passado um json e sim um código html